# CV Parser name matching

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, data-science, named-entity-recognition

I am using NLP with python to find the names from the string. I am able to find the if i have a full name (first name and last name) but in the string i have only first name means my code is not able to recognize as Person. Below is my code.

```
import re
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop = stopwords.words('english')

string = """
Sriram is working as a python developer 
"""


def ie_preprocess(document):
    document = ' '.join([i for i in document.split() if i not in stop])
    sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(document)
    sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sentences]
    sentences = [nltk.pos_tag(sent) for sent in sentences]
    return sentences

def extract_names(document):
    names = []
    sentences = ie_preprocess(document)
    #print(sentences)
    for tagged_sentence in sentences:
        for chunk in nltk.ne_chunk(tagged_sentence):
            #print("Out Side ",chunk)
            if type(chunk) == nltk.tree.Tree:

                if chunk.label() == 'PERSON':
                    print("In Side ",chunk)
                    names.append(' '.join([c[0] for c in chunk]))
    return names

if __name__ == '__main__':
    names = extract_names(string)
    print(names)
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to use the StanfordNLP/Spacy NER, using nltk ne chunks is a little janky. StanfordNLP is more commonly used by researchers, but Spacy is easier to work with. Here is an example using Spacy to print the name of each named entity and its type:

```
>>> import spacy
>>> nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
>>> text = 'Sriram is working as a python developer'
>>> doc = nlp(text)
>>> for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text,ent.label_)


Sriram ORG
>>>
```

Note that it classifies Sriram as an organization, which may be because it is not a common English name and Spacy is trained on English corpa. Good luck!

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. But in place of text if i pass a profile/resume then it will identify a lot of names but it wont make sense right. Because is not fast so definitely it will take time

Comment: Hey sorry I didn't see you earlier! The advantage to Spacy is that it is super fast. You can pass multiple documents to have them processed fairly fast. If speed is really an issue for you, Spacy is built in Cython and you could keep it all Cythonic to avoid GIL. I'd do some benchmarks just to see how long it will take. Write a simple script to output the named ents for resumes and do a test run feeding it only a few and see how it runs.  If it is too long, you can start by multiprocessing and looking for cute optimizations. If that isn't enough, get out the big guns (Cython).